# How do I delete duplicates in my array merging method?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a method that takes 2 attributes which are 2 arrays and merges them in the ascending order. All that's left for me is to figure out how to delete duplicates. Here's the code:

```
public static int[] mergeArrays(int[] a, int[] b){

    int[] c = new int[a.length+b.length];
    int aIt = 0;
    int bIt = 0;

    while(true) {


        if(aIt < a.length && bIt < b.length) {
            if(a[aIt] == b[bIt]){
                c[aIt+bIt] = a[aIt++];
            }
            else{
                c[aIt+bIt] = b[bIt++];
            }
        } else if(aIt < a.length) {
            c[aIt+bIt] = a[aIt++];
        } else if(bIt < b.length) {
            c[aIt+bIt] = b[bIt++];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

As you can imagine, this is an assignment, so I'm not supposed to use any external libraries, otherwise this would be a lot easier.

I tried this method, but when I run this code in the console it seems to put it in some never-ending loop which consumes my CPU core entirely until I stop the process:

```
public static int[] mergeArrays(int[] a, int[] b){

    int[] c = new int[a.length+b.length];
    int aIt = 0;
    int bIt = 0;
    int lastVal = 0;
    while(true) {
        if(c[aIt+bIt] == lastVal){
            continue;
        }
        else{
            if(aIt < a.length && bIt < b.length) {
                if(a[aIt] == b[bIt]){
                    c[aIt+bIt] = a[aIt++];
                    lastVal = c[aIt+bIt];
                }
                else{
                    c[aIt+bIt] = b[bIt++];
                    lastVal = c[aIt+bIt];
                }
            } else if(aIt < a.length) {
                c[aIt+bIt] = a[aIt++];
                lastVal = c[aIt+bIt];
            } else if(bIt < b.length) {
                c[aIt+bIt] = b[bIt++];
                lastVal = c[aIt+bIt];
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

It seems as though the "continue" keyword is the problem. When I try break in its place, the code executes.

EDIT:

I've added a new array to the mergeArrays method:

```
public static int[] mergeArrays(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    int a_size = a.length;
    int b_size = b.length;
    int[] c = new int[a_size + b_size];
    int[] d = null;
    int i = 0 , j = 0, x = -1;
    for(; i < a_size && j < b_size;)
    {
        if(a[i] <= b[j])
        {
            c[++x] = a[i];
            ++i;
            }
        else          
        {
            if(c[x] != b[j])
            {
                c[++x] = b[j]; // avoid duplicates
            }
            ++j;
            }
            }
            --i; --j;
            while(++i < a_size)
            {
                c[++x] = a[i];
            }
            while(++j < b_size)
            {
                c[++x] = b[j];
            }
    d = new int[uniqueValues(c)];        

    for(int g=0; g<uniqueValues(c); g++){
        d[g] = c[g];
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: no one is going to write your homework for you. you need to make an effort and at least start with something. when you encounter a specific problem, we can help you on that

Comment: I've added the method I've tried

Comment: the endless loop will occur is `c[0]` contain `0`

Comment: are you allowed to sort the arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can certainly do these in following two steps task :

> Sort both the arrays.

```
static void sortArray(int[] a) {
    for (int lastPos = a.length - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--) {
        for (int index = 0; index <= lastPos - 1; index++) {
            if (a[index] > a[index + 1]) {
                int temp = a[index];
                a[index] = a[index + 1];
                a[index + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Remove duplicates while merging them.

```
public static int[] mergeArrays(int[] a, int[] b)
        {
            int a_size = a.length;
            int b_size = b.length;
            int[] c = new int[a_size + b_size];
            int i = 0 , j = 0, x = -1;
            for(; i < a_size && j < b_size;)
            {
                if(a[i] <= b[j])
                {
                    c[++x] = a[i];
                    ++i;
                    }
                else          
                {
                    if(c[x] != b[j])
                    {
                        c[++x] = b[j]; // avoid duplicates
                    }
                    ++j;
                    }
                    }
                    --i; --j;
                    while(++i < a_size)
                    {
                        c[++x] = a[i];
                    }
                    while(++j < b_size)
                    {
                        c[++x] = b[j];
                    }
                    return c;
                    }
```

> Count unique values in newly merged array.

```
static int uniqueValues(int[] c) {
    int uniqueValues = c.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        while (c[i] == c[i + 1] && i + 1 < c.length && c[i] > c[i+1] ) {
            i++;
            uniqueValues--;
        }
    }
    return unique;
}
```

> Reestablish the merged array with unique value count i.e. delete the remaining elements after count finishes.

```
sortArray(a);
sortArray(b);
int[] c = mergeArrays(a, b);
c = deleteDuplicateEntries(c, uniqueValues(c));
```

Let me know if you find it useful.

Comment: This is almost perfect, except that it leaves 0 values at the end of the arrays for the amount of duplicates it merged. So if I inputed arrays like 1, 2, 3 and 1, 2, 4, it'll return 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0

Comment: @Vapor Trails : We can provide another method which will count the unique values in both the arrays and then set the new array of that size. Let me update the post.

Comment: Yes, but that will still count all those 0 and return one 0 for the last index. And getting rid of values with 0 isn't a solution either.

Comment: @Vapor Trails : Just check out how uniqueValue method is operating to get the unique count. You will see that unique count only decreases if 2 neighbouring elements are same. So if your merged array is like [0,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0] it will give a unique count of 5 exactly.

Comment: Okay.. but why not simply use `SortedSet`?

Comment: @Ayush : That's a good suggestion. Also the first which came to my mind. But here at community we don't try to provide new solutions, instead we try to solve them the way they are asked to be otherwise we won't be here.

Comment: It's an assignment, as I mentioned, so we're not allowed to use any extra help except raw Java functionalities.

Comment: @VaporTrails `SortedSet` is a part of core java

Comment: I meant no imports

Comment: @learner8269 I think you forgot to define deleteDuplicateEntries method.

Comment: @Vapor Trails : You can just create a new array from merged array and of size uniqueValue. Do you still want me to write it or can you do it. Let me know.

Comment: I just created a new array with the length of uniqueValues value, but I'm getting NullPointerException inside the uniqueValues method inside the while clause.

Comment: Try providing i<c.length-1 inside for loop of mmethod

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it. I edited my original post to show my latest addition where I initialized a new array instead of just returning c and assigning it length of c unique values and values of c, but what it returns is the same array as c.

Comment: If that's the problem just return a new array inside new array variable to get the work done. Also if interested and have time just explore more on arrays.

Comment: Actually the method uniqueValues doesn't work, as it returns the number of total values, not uniqueValues.

Comment: I'll figure it out, you've gotten me far enough. Thanks for your input, it was really helpful. I've upvoted, tho I don't have enough rep for it to show and I'll pick your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let the libraries work for you:

*(Note, that outside of jshell, you have to terminate each non-empty line with ";")*

```
int[] ai = {0, 1, 15, 16, 27, 84, 49, 4, 5 }
int[] bi = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 4, 5 }

List <Integer> li = new ArrayList<> ()
Arrays.stream (ai).forEach (i -> li.add (new Integer (i))) 
Arrays.stream (bi).forEach (i -> li.add (new Integer (i))) 
Collections.sort (li)
int [] res = li.stream().distinct().mapToInt (i -> i.intValue()).toArray()
```

result in jshell:

```
for (int i: res) System.out.printf (" %d", i); 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 15 16 27 49 84
```